# just cloned input field (last) can be added for mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I made a form in which the user can clone/duplicate a input field with JQuery for adding more informations. The problem is just the last cloned input is available in the sent mail.

I tried with PHP something like this:

```
$product = "";
$product.= $_POST['product'] .= "\t amount".$trenner.$_POST['amount'] .= "\t price".$trenner.$_POST['price']."€";
```

But it doesn't work.

Jquery:

```
var products = $(".products").clone();
var clonedRow = products.clone().insertAfter(".products:last").find(":input").val(this.value ).end();
//ajax
console.log(products,clonedRow,$('[name="Product"]', clonedRow))
```

Comment: Your input name has to be `amount[]`, then you can get values in PHP as `array`.

Comment: Thanks for anwser @ReneKorss. You mean like that: <input type="text" name="amount[]" placeholder="amount"required/> and $product.= "\t amount".$trenner.$_POST['amount[]']

Comment: Seems isn´t working for me like that.

Comment: Side issue: By directly interpolating user-supplied values into your HTML output (`$product.= $_POST['product']`...) you are opening yourself up to various security problems. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your input name should have `[]` in end of it, so it can have multiple values.

```
<input type="text" name="amount[]" placeholder="amount" required />
```

In PHP, you will get it like usual:

```
$amounts = $_POST['amount']; // array
```

but now it is `array`, so you can't concatenate it like regular value. You could, for example join values together separated with comma `,`.

This can be done with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$amounts = implode(', ', $_POST['amount']);
$product.= $_POST['product'] .= "\t amount".$trenner.$amounts .= "\t price".$trenner.$_POST['price']."€";
```

Point here is that you must use array values and generate some string out of it.

If you want to sum them together, you can use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

```
$sum = array_sum($_POST['amount']);
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to explain it to you.:)